# create multiple login pages asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I created a web application in ASP.Net and the default login page is in the file ~/account/login.aspx. The file 'account' has its own web config. I would like to have a login page to select the admin folder or the user folder. What can I add or change to the web config file? I didn't do anything yet...I just opened a new application.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need two login pages?

Comment: Sorry, i will not have problem to have one Login page and from there to select the admin or user...I forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to assign different role to the user and then you can set the authorization .

your steps are

click the "Configure ASP.NET" button on the top-right hand corner of the Solution Explorer. If you navigate to the Security section, you can start creating Users and Roles. The tool basically describes exactly how they work to you.

[image: roles]
<sub>(source: [4guysfromrolla.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20211023121855/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/images/roles1.jpg))</sub>